# How to automatically update coordinates in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I tried "$x" and "$y" for coordinates but it always give me zero "0" values too, and what I really want is to display the coordinates like in this image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange Vítor! The StackExchange format can take some getting used to. One core idea is that every thread should contain only one question. The above text addresses three independent issues: one about date formatting, one about scale, and the other about how to create a grid. Please post them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [grid option](http://anitagraser.com/2013/03/24/print-composer-2-0-take-5-map-grids/) which is part of the map item's properties:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Anita, but, today, in the afternoon, I explored qgis composer, and had already achieved that goal. But I had no luck with $x or $y expressions (and $scale). Could you give me a little help with it? Thank you again

PS: Congratulations for your new book, I'll try to buy it as soon as possible :)

Comment: @VítorJorge For $scale insert a scalebar item. It can be set to display scale in a numeric style instead of a classic bar. What would you expect as a result of $x or $y? These don't seem to make sense in a print composer use case.

Comment: ♦ Well, I'm using lizmap web client, and I don't know why but it doesn't assume the coord grid or the scale bar. I contacted René-Luc (lizmap programmer) and he said that's a qgis server bug. On the other hand, uster has the grid with qgis web client, don't know how :| So I was trying to use expressions to see if I could somehow solve the situation...just testing, maybe with expressions it could appear on lizmap but even on qgis print composer it always give me zero "0" values, and I wonder why ;) I'm not a qgis expert, just using it because of lizmap :D Hope you can help me somehow